# How to change this Heart pattern in Python?

Tags: python

I was seeing this heart pattern in python.
but i don't know how i can improve this to get a number from user as input and give a valid heart pattern as well. 
As you can see this pattern has three parts and one is printing stars and  white spaces. So here goes the code that if you run its small sized. i want to decrease and increase his size with input of user.

```
for row in range(6):
    for col in range(7): 
        if(row==0 and col%3!=0 or (row==1 and col%3==0) or (row-col==2) or (row+col==8)): 
            print("*", end="" ) 
        else: 
            print( end=" " ) 
    print()
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does user input stand for?

Comment: I mean we can take an input from user to increase or decrease the size of heart.